# How to setFetchSize in Hive with JDBC Driver 0.13.0

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am running a query against a Hive/Hadoop that returns 100.000 rows, and I would like to enable setFetchSize, to not have as many rows at once, and I am using Hive JDBC driver for that.

The point is that the same query is also ran against a postgres, or may actually be ran in other relational databases, so that makes sense to use this size feature to control it.

The problem is that when I call the method setFetchSize, I keep getting the following

**java.sql.SQLException: Method not supported
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HivePreparedStatement.setFetchSize(HivePreparedStatement.java:1229) ~[hive-jdbc-0.13.0.jar:0.13.0]**

This method is not supported, how can I work this around and achieve the same goal?

Comment: Does it really matter for you to use a `PreparedStatement` instead of a plain `Statement`? And did you try a more recent version of the driver?

Comment: Hi @SamsonScharfrichter, I am running with Hive 0.13.0, when I tried to a different vervion, for instance, Apache Hive 0.13.0 and the driver 1.1.0, it did not work! Then I tried with different version, but the connection is only open when I use the same driver version. How can I achoeve the same effect of setFetchSize

Comment: I know for sure that `setFetchSize` works for "Statement" in Hive 0.13.1 as packaged in the HortonWorks distro. Never tried with "PreparedStatement" nor with the base Apache distro, though. And I also know for sure that the 0.13 driver works against a 0.14 service (HortonWorks both); maybe the gap with 1.1 is too wide for compatibility.

Comment: Hey @SamsonScharfrichter, what abou Hive Hadoop from Cloudera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try to set on the resultSet level, we are currently also using `0.13.0` And calling `rs.setFetchSize(5000);` works perfect for us. The Spring JdbcTemplate code snippet is something like:

```
hiveJdbcTemplate.query(sqlToExecute, rs -> {
            rs.setFetchSize(5000);
            while (rs.next()){
               ....do you handling
            }
        });
```

Hopefully this would work for you. The default fetchSize is just 50 which is way to small if you need to fetch millions of rows. From `Hive 1.3.0` onward, this problem is solved by increasing the default from 50 to 1000. The Apache Hive Jira ticket is: HIVE-11429.